# Vertical space of \includegraphics[height=2cm]

Tags: graphics, spacing, vertical-alignment

I am trying to place an image on the right of some individual lines of text that do not stretch over the entire `\textwidth`. The image will go higher than the first line and I have to be able to position the image very precisely. My idea was:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\textwidth=5cm
\begin{document}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
A\\
B\\[-2cm]
C\hfill\includegraphics[height=2cm]{testimg}\\
D
\end{document}
```

which produces

[image]

What I don't like is that `B` and `C` are not on the same line, which means that in the the space between `B` and `D` is larger than the space between `B` and `A` (`C` will not be in the final document, it is just inserted for illustration).

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should put the image in a vertical version of `\rlap` so that officially it doesn't take any vertical space. You can do this like this:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\textwidth=5cm
\begin{document}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
A\\
B\hspace{4cm}\hbox to 0pt{\vbox to 0pt{\vss\rule{5cm}{2cm}}\hss}\\
D
\end{document}
```

(Here `\rule` is a demo replacement of the `\includegraphics`)

This also makes the image officially 0pt wide and you can position it using the value of `\hspace`.

However, you could control the position even more exact if you put both the text and the image into a picture environment like e.g. `tikzpicture`.

Comment: It's dangerous to use a box like this because you can erase something above the picture. You can try `\hfill\rule{5cm}{2cm}`  before `A` for example.

Comment: @Altermundus: Sure, but the original code with `\\[-2cm]` isn't better. I wouldn't do this in general but in the OP's case if you want it this way and know that there is nothing covered by the image you can use it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I have been trying to integrate it into my document. Two things I struggle with: (a) Since the hbox is 0pt, I can't use \hfill to align the image on the right page border. (b) In this approach, is there a way to control the vertical position of the image also? I realized that I might want the image bottom to be between two lines (Sorry, this last requirement was not mentioned in my question).

Comment: @Frank: You don't need to make the `\hbox` 0pt wide. Just remove the ` to 0pt` after it. Also you can try `\raisebox{<value>}{<content>}` to adjust the vertical positioning.

Comment: `\raisebox` worked great! I am not having luck with `\hfill \hbox {\vbox to 0pt {...`, however: The image is placed right next to the letters...

Answer (score 1):

Possibly two minipages (remark: the use of `\\` inside a document should be avoided):

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\begin{minipage}[c]{.45\textwidth}
A

B

C
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}[b]{.45\textwidth}
\includegraphics[height=2cm]{testimg}
\end{minipage} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: why do you say that the use of `\\ ` should be avoided?

Comment: @Gonzalo Outside a table, a \\ specifies the end of a paragraph, and the start of a new one, which is not indented. It's a linebreaking. It's useful in some cases but generally you stop TeX to do is natural work. This is ok in a title but I prefer to avoid it to format text lines. But perhaps I'm wrong .. :(

Comment: but `\\ ` doesn't end a paragraph; `\\ ` starts a new line inside an existing paragraph! On the other hand, I don't understand what you mean by "you stop TeX to do its natural work". The command `\\ ` properly used is really very handy.

Comment: @Gonzalo  You are right I don't use the good verb but my english is not good.`\\`  forces a linebreak somewhere in a block of text, and forces LaTeX to start a new line, but not a new paragraph. It is not `to end` but to `break` the line and a paragraph. It's not natural inside a paragraph to break a line like that, but perhaps it's only a french approach and it's possible with another language.  I understand it's useful in some specific cases and  this command can be used properly. But not too much ... and not everywhere